using asyncio to detect all online host in the local area network
I am trying to convert a code that used multiprocessing and Queue to detect host on the network to asyncio
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import socket
import time
import subprocess
import os



def pinger(ip):
    """
    Do Ping
    :return: ip
    """
    print(f"{ip}")
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(
            ['ping', '-c1', ip],
            stdout=DEVNULL
        )
        return True
    except:
        pass


def get_my_ip():
    """
    Find my IP address
    :return:
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("192.168.1.1", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    print("My ip is: {}".format(ip))
    s.close()
    return ip


async def main():
    pool_size = 255
    start = 102
    # get my IP and compose a base like 192.168.1.xxx
    ip_parts = get_my_ip().split('.')
    base_ip = ip_parts[0] + '.' + ip_parts[1] + '.' + ip_parts[2] + '.'

    tasks = []

    for i in range(start, pool_size):
        task = asyncio.create_task(pinger(f"{base_ip}{i}"))
        tasks.append(task)

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

but this result in weirdness:
    task = asyncio.create_task(pinger(f"{base_ip}{i}"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 337, in create_task
    task = loop.create_task(coro)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 438, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name)
TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got True

What am I doing wrong? I want to ping all possible IP all at once.

Issue
Just as error message said! Let's look into the signature:

asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None, context=None)
Wrap the coro Corutine into a Task and schedule its execution. Return the Task object.

Pinger is not a coroutine!
>>> def some_synchronous_func():
...     pass
>>>
>>> some_synchronous_func
<function some_synchronous_func at 0x0000028389343100>


But Async functions are a functions that returns coroutine.
>>> async def some_async_func():
...     pass
>>>
>>> some_async_func
<function some_async_func at 0x0000028388D8BC40>

>>> some_async_func()
<coroutine object some_async_func at 0x000002838906FD70>



Fix
To fix, you either:

Deligate syncrhonous function call using asyncio.to_thread()
asyncio.subprocess_open() instead as written at this answer

Latter is recommended, as it does not create additional thread (iirc). Consider to_thread() as last resort.

This is working code for WINDOWS - change command accordingly for *nix.
import asyncio
import socket
import subprocess


from typing import Awaitable


# --- Config ---

IP_CHECK_START = 102
IP_CHECK_END = 255


# --- Async Check Call Implementations ---

async def _check_call(task_id: int, cmd: str) -> Awaitable[bool]:
    """Run a command and return True if successful.
    
    Raises:
        subprocess.CalledProcessError: If command fails with non-zero return code
    """

    print(f"[Task {task_id}] started")
    try:
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        )

        await proc.wait()
        if proc.returncode:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd)
    finally:
        print(f"[Task {task_id}] done")


async def _check_call_threaded(task_id: int, cmd: str) -> Awaitable[bool]:
    """Use to_thread to delegate check_call.
    
    Raises:
        subprocess.CalledProcessError: If command fails with non-zero return code
    """

    print(f"[Task {task_id}] started")
    try:
        await asyncio.to_thread(
            subprocess.check_call, cmd, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
        )
    finally:
        print(f"[Task {task_id}] done")


# --- Utility Func ---

async def ping_dat(task_id: int, ip: str) -> Awaitable[bool]:
    """
    Ping this, ping that!

    Args:
        task_id: Task's ID
        ip: IP address to ping

    Returns:
        True if reachable, False otherwise
    """

    try:
        # native call
        await _check_call(task_id, f"ping /w 2 {ip}")

        # or threaded call - not recommended
        # await _check_call_threaded(task_id, f"ping /w 2 {ip}")

        print(f"[Task {task_id}] {ip} is reachable")
        return True

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        # on failed command with return code other than 0,
        # CalledProcessError is raised for subprocess.check_call
        print(f"[Task {task_id}] {ip} is not reachable")
        return False


# --- Driver ---

async def main():
    # get ip
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print("IP Address:", ip)

    ip_parts = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).split('.')
    base_ip = ".".join(ip_parts[:-1]) + "."

    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(ping_dat(idx, f"{base_ip}{addr}"))
        for idx, addr in enumerate(range(IP_CHECK_START, IP_CHECK_END + 1))
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

IP Address: [REDACTED]
[Task 0] started
[Task 1] started
[Task 2] started
[Task 3] started
[Task 4] started
[Task 3] done
[Task 3] [REDACTED] is reachable
[Task 1] done
[Task 1] [REDACTED] is not reachable
[Task 0] done
[Task 0] [REDACTED] is not reachable
[Task 4] done
[Task 4] [REDACTED] is not reachable
[Task 2] done
[Task 2] [REDACTED] is not reachable

Also read below if you're interested about asynchronous itself.


Rule of async-native programming
1. Remember difference between (Async)Concurrency vs Parallel. Former is hardly working, latter is hard working!
To copy what I wrote at other answer

IO Operations are basically just like this:

"Hey OS, please do this IO works for me. Wake me up when it's done."
Thread 1 goes to sleep
Some time later, OS punches Thread 1
"Your IO Operation is done, take this and get back to work."

So all it does is Doing Nothing - for such cases, aka IO Bound stuffs,
GIL can be safely released and let other threads to run. Built-in
functions like time.sleep, open(), etc implements such GIL release
logic in their C code.


2. All the async-await call chain should end up with async library's Awaitable.
>>> async def do_that():
...     print("Doing that")
...     await do_this()
...     print("Done that")
>>>
>>> async def do_this():
...     print("Doing this")
...     await asyncio.sleep(5)  # <---
...     print("Done this")
>>>
>>> asyncio.run(do_that())
Doing that
Doing this
Done this
Done that

This is because asyncio is internally (iirc) Doing nothing until OS wakes them up upon certain events. At the end of the async-await chain there's such code that does the event listening it for us, so we don't have to do it ourselves.

...yeah that's honestly all you need to write a working asyncio code. You can read more here about shortcomings of asyncio too if interested!

I replaced task id with time i.e. i used print(f"{current:%H:%M:%S}   {ip}") and I saw even though all the IPs are passed directly to multiple lanes of processing done in order the for loop dictated the pool it returns the result in time it took to process as expected. however the test also showed some that took more time happened to return result later and some that took less time happened to result  last. To experiment I used socket.gethostname() or nmap library to get the remote hostname. Thank you for explanation.

sorry I couldn't understand sentence to full, would you mind breaking down into shorter sentenses? Are you curious why some takes shorter time while some takes longer? or, lemme know what you want to fix!
